# $F(x) = \int_0^{x} t^2 e^{t^2}dt$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, derivatives

Let $y_0 = f''(2) + f'(1) + f(0)$ if $f$ is a real function defined by $f(x) = \int_0^{x} t^2 e^{t^2}dt$.

How can I calculate the value of the expression $y_0$.

I tried use the fundamental theorem of calculus,i.e, if $f(x) = \int_0^{x} t^2 e^{t^2}\;\mathrm{d}t$ then $f'(x)= x^2 e^{x^2}$ then $f'(1)= e$ but i stuck when I use it for $f''$.  Some help please.

Comment: Just differentiate $x^2 e^{x^2}$, using the product rule and the chain rule.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$(x^2e^{x^2})´=(2x+2x^3)e^{x^2}$$

Comment: Is the prime symbol outside the bracket valid notation?

Comment: @Aapeli Why not?  It's clear that he means $f''(x) = \frac{d}{dx}\frac{df}{dx} = \frac{d}{dx}\left(x^2e^{x^2}\right)$ so what different does the notation makes when it is clear?

Comment: @Aapeli The prime symbol to indicate derivative is a commonly accepted shorthand, *as long as it is clear with respect to which variable the derivative is taken*.  $f'(x) = (f(x))' = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} x} f(x)$